# When will Qiskit Runtime be available to all users?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

IBM's [Qiskit Runtime](https://research.ibm.com/blog/120x-quantum-speedup) was recently made available to a select group of users. Have they announced when it will be available to all users or when they might open it back up to a second round of new users?

Comment: Not sure if this is considered the first or second round, but Qiskit Runtime is now available on `ibmq_qasm_simulator` for all premium users.

Comment: I am looking specifically to use it on real qc hardware. Has IBMQ discussed when that will be available to users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiskit runtime is now available on [`ibmq_qasm_simualtor`](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=simulators&system=ibmq_qasm_simulator) for the public using the default open provider.

Qiskit runtime for real quantum system was also available for the participants during [IBM Quantum Challenge Fall 2021](https://research.ibm.com/blog/fall-2021-quantum-challenge-results) for a limited time in Oct 27-Nov 6 2021:

Answer (score 2):

I asked on the Qiskit Slack and got this answer (translated from Spanish):

> Runtime has no official release date for regular users. Right now, only certain IBM partners have access to help with debugging.

So, it seems they haven’t defined a date for public release yet.

Answer (score 1):

In Sept. 2021, they announced that the Qiskit runtime has been enabled on all IBM Quantum systems on slack. Follow this link for more https://qiskit.slack.com/archives/C8GLMQ1U5/p1631806010144500. There also exists a jupyter notebook in the qiskit-tutorials folder where you can find, how to give your own program to the qiskit runtime service.